# Can portal users be authenticated with a connected app?

Tags: single-sign-on, community, connected-apps, saml, portal

I saw a webinar http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MsKJs23W3I on social sign on.  Is  it possible for user which registered using facebook or janrain to login and use  Connected apps?? Or social sign on is only for Portals ??

Comment: Are you asking whether or not it is possible to use a connected app in a community, regardless of how they logged in or are you asking whether or not it is possible to use a Connected App as a login / auth mechanism to a community?

Comment: i am asking about connected app as a login /auth mechanism to a community.

Comment: I'm very confused about this question. You can configure Facebook, Janrain, Salesforce, or any OpenID Connect provider as an **authentication provider** to login to Portal (or, now, Communities). A connected app can leverage a user's login to call API's, but it's not a login mechanism with respect to Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

During the login process of a connected the user is prompted for their Salesforce username and password. They have no option to login using Facebook or some other social sign in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Social Sign-ons with Salesforce Communities product by setting up authentication provider in SFDC and configuring your Communities instance appropriately. Refer to the SFDC documentation and this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15287/using-facebook-as-an-idp-with-salesforce-in-oauth).

Once configured, you can use it for connected apps (such as mobile apps). This blog post explains the process for a native mobile app accessing a Salesforce Communities instance using a Social sign-on. HTH!

[Native mobile app for Salesforce Communities - Part 2 (Authentication)](http://www.kaizenmantra.net/blog/2013/12/24/native-mobile-app-for-salesforce-communities-part-2-authentication)

Answer (score 1):

As stated it [this](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_addl_params_start.htm&language=en_US#sso_provider_addl_params_start.xml) SalesForce doc, and tested by me in my org, you can use the social sign-in as follows:
Point the user to the following URL:

https://login.salesforce.com/services/auth/sso/{*orgID*}/{*URLsuffix*}?community=https://{*your community domain*}.force.com/

- *orgId* - It's your Auth. Provider ID
- *URLsuffix* is the value you specified when you defined the authentication provider

Answer (score 0):

Sounds possible, connected apps sent on top of SFDC authentication. So if the user can login to SFDC (including communities) via their facebook or janrain credentials, they'll be able to use the connected app.

Comment: how to acheive this ?? How to login in Connected app in salesforce using facebook please guideline a little.

Comment: @user133421 I'd suggest researching your options for logging portal users into Salesforce with Janrain and Facebook first.  If you're stuck ask another question on this forum.  Unfortunately I don't know exactly how that piece would work, just that all the connected app cares about is that they're logged into Salesforce.  After that it doesn't matter how they're authenticated to the connected app.